# Can Go (CI server) send mail for each failed build regardless of pipeline?

Tags: thoughtworks-go

I'm using [Go](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/go-continuous-delivery/) as my continuous integration server. I'm trying to get it to send an email if any stage in any pipeline breaks. So far, all I've found is a [per-user email configuration](http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/go/14.2.0/help/dev_notifications.html), which forces me to add an email event per stage, per pipeline and per event. With 15 stages across 10 pipelines, and 3 events to trigger on, that's a lot of configuration.

Is it possible to configure it for all pipelines and all stages at once?

Comment: Also posted at http://serverfault.com/q/666390/9846, but no one seems to know there :(

Comment: I dislike the "failure handling". I ended up writing a script to interrogate pipelines for failures and push them to our chatops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post Go [14.3](http://www.go.cd/releases/#14.3) you can add notifications for all pipelines and all stages at once. You would need to select the option similar to the one shown in the image below:

[image: set notification for any pipeline any stage]

You could refer to the [documentation](http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/configuration/dev_notifications.html) for more details.